# Null pointer exception when using interceptor

Tags: java, interception

I'm using interceptors for the first time. I followed the course of A. Goncalves, I tried to implement a simple logger interceptor as follows but I got a NPE. I don't understand what is wrong, please explain to me.
I used a Qualifier.

**Qualifier implementation**

```
package classes;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;

@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD,TYPE})
public @interface Loggable {

}
```

**Interceptor implementation**

```
package classes;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

@Loggable
@Interceptor
public class LoggingInterceptor {

    private Logger logger;

    @AroundInvoke
    private Object intercept(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception{
        logger.info("> Entry");
        return ic.proceed();
    }
}
```

**Controller implementation**

```
package classes;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Loggable
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class BookService implements Serializable{

    public BookService (){
    }

    @Inject
    @ThirteenDigits
    private NumberGenerator generator;

    @Loggable
    public void somePrintMethod(){
        System.err.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

**XHTML page implemenation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      >
    <h:head>
        <title>Interceptor</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="Create" action="#{bookService.somePrintMethod}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**Error**

> Avertissement: #{bookService.somePrintMethod}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException javax.faces.FacesException:
>
> ## {bookService.somePrintMethod}: java.lang.NullPointerException    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
>
> at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     ... 31 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   classes.LoggingInterceptor.intercept(LoggingInterceptor.java:25)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleMethodInvocation.java:30)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:112)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:88)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:53)
>     at
>   classes.BookService$Proxy$_$$*WeldSubclass.somePrintMethod(BookService$Proxy$*$$_WeldSubclass.java)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)  at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
>     ... 32 more

Comment: Well, the flag of my question as a duplicate pushed me to thing otehrwise. I replaced the code of the `LoggingInterceptor` by the following code and it worked `@Loggable
@Interceptor
@Getter
public class LoggingInterceptor {
    
    private static Logger LOGGER;
    
    public LoggingInterceptor(){
        LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("Some text");
    }
    
    @AroundInvoke
    private Object intercept(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception{
        LOGGER.info("> Entry");
        return ic.proceed();
    }
}`

Comment: Are you sure the Logger is properly injected in your Interceptor?

Comment: @sn42 short answer: I'm not sure. Long one: I had a problem with inject in my interceptor. In the course it is written `@Inject` before the Logger, using that caused me an error that I couldn't understand. I tried many things to solve it, removing `@Inject` made the code work fine. But I don't understand why!!

Comment: @sn42 when I sue the code of the course `@Loggable
@Interceptor
public class LoggingInterceptor {

    @Inject
    private Logger LOGGER;
    
    @AroundInvoke
    private Object intercept(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception{
        LOGGER.info("> Entry");
        return ic.proceed();
    }
}` I get the following error `Grave: Exception while loading the app : WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Logger] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private classes.LoggingInterceptor.LOGGER]`